# Seeking clarification onAsynchronous Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

If javascript is single threaded and asynchronous ..we we make ajax calls , the code after ajax call will get executed with out waiting for the response.

But when the response come from the server , does the  thread suspend the execution of the present  code and move to the call back function in the ajax call as it is single threaded?

Comment: Each function that needs to be run is put on something called the `call stack`. The engine runs through all the functions on the call stack until there's nothing left to do. Check out this video that does a pretty good job explaining the `JavaScript` call stack: https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-call-stack

Comment: Definitely this concise presentation on the event loop https://2014.jsconf.eu/speakers/philip-roberts-what-the-heck-is-the-event-loop-anyway.html by Philip Roberts.